# Is "which there wasn't" putting it right?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns, grammatical-number

Please note that I'm not a native speaker.

Take this sentence:

> Even if there would have been sufficient eggs — which there wasn’t — he would need other stuff sooner or later.

Is the wording "which there wasn't" grammatically correct and would a native speaker understand that, in fact, there were not sufficient eggs?

Comment: Should be "which there weren't" - eggs is plural - you caught that yourself in your last sentence: "Is the wording "which there wasn't" grammatically correct and would a native speaker understand that, in fact, there ***were not*** sufficient eggs? :-)

Comment: "Sufficient eggs" is not quite idiomatic. A native speaker would be likely to say "enough eggs".   Your parenthetic "which there wasn't|weren't" is redundant, since "Even if" already conveys the meaning that there were not enough eggs. **Sufficient** and **stuff** are in somewhat different registers.

Comment: It is also possible to understand "which" as referring back to the existential statement not to the noun "eggs" in particular, and thus the singular "wasn't" would be acceptable.

Comment: The redundancy isn't a problem, though.  It adds emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

I think a native speaker would understand, but it is gramatically correct to say "which there weren't".

I think this is because you can count eggs and say that eggs "were" or "weren't".  Substitute in a mass noun like milk, then you should say that milk "was" or "wasn't".